# Help me identify my classic frame

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, vintage, campagnolo

Can anyone identify this classic frame?
I don't know if this frame I got is generic or branded. I got no signs of any brand except for the Brev Campagnolo drop out and a raised C-69-E under the frame.

[image]

Comment: These questions would be much easier to answer before spray painting the bike. Almost as if someone tried to hide its identity.

Comment: Is the frame steel ?  test with a magnet.   (I expect so)   You can also query the seller, probably best done before commiting to purchase.

Comment: Brev. is short for brevetto, which means patented in Italian. Campagnolo is the firm that manufactured the dropout. These days they do components, wheels, and some soft goods, but they ceased making dropouts some time ago. I’m not familiar with classic frames, but a Campy (or Campag if you’re in the UK) dropout means the frame is probably a decent one. I have no way of knowing how decent.

Comment: Fairly generic good-quality bike from around 1980.  I had one that looked almost identical, but I can't remember what the brand was.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I swapped my fixie for that. I only care about the classic looks until I discovered the drop out name. The guy says its a campagnolo frame but my friends says that company dont manufacture frames. From then i got curious. Thanks btw

Comment: It's difficult to identify an unbranded frame unless the framebuilder had a signature touch, as some do. I agree this looks like a mainstream, generic frame.

Comment: C-69-E is the bottom bracket shell part number. From what I can tell based on forum conversations it's a Cinelli number. Sadly, this will not help you identify the frame. That shell was used by several frame makers. https://www.bicycles.net.au/forums/viewtopic.php?t=76848. They were only used on very good frames, usually European or American made.

Comment: Did you look closely all over the frame for a serial number? If not on the bottom bracket it might be on a rear dropout or the seat tube or the head tube? The inner seat tube diameter is also a good indicator of tubing quality if you can determine it accurately

Comment: While this is nitpicky and a tangent, I wonder what generic frame means in this context. In the modern context, a number of companies offer open mold carbon frames. Here, a factory will offer several designs for sale, and frame companies in the West will select and brand those frames and handle warranties and quality control. I'd consider those frames to be generic. By contrast, the big name frame companies will tend to have proprietary frames, even though they manufacture in the Far East. Is there a parallel process with older steel frames? What would count as a generic one?

Comment: I take your point. By "generic" I simply meant "nothing distinctive about it." Even in the 80s, there were bike brands that used contract manufacture in Taiwan; at least some were buying existing designs and slapping their decals on them. That could be considered truly "generic."

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a well made steel frame that probably has good quality butted tubing and seems to be quite racy with a fairly tight geometry. Looking at the Campagnolo dropouts doesn't tell us much as they were in a long production over decades. The sloping fork crown and the recessed brake nuts date this to being an 80s or even early 90s race frame. The seat stay/seat tube interface is pretty standard and the lugs look like unmodified generic parts from some lug makers catalogue so the frame could have been made by any number of framebuilders that used to churn them out either under their own name or rebranded for a shop to sell (like Dave Russell in Slough as the first example that comes to mind). The fact it has very little lettering or numbering means it could have been a custom job, or the other numbers could be lost. Whatever the real answer, it's a good quality frame and should be a great ride.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. So my frame is not branded but not totally fake i guess. Haha!